# Oracle query to show active queries is showing finished queries

Tags: oracle

I have the following code to display the active running queries in the DB.

```
SELECT a.sql_id,
  sql_exec_start,
  a.inst_id,
  a.sid,
  a.serial#,
  a.username,
  b.sql_text
FROM gv$session a
INNER JOIN gv$sqlarea b
ON a.sql_id     = b.sql_id
WHERE a.inst_id = b.inst_id
AND a.status    = 'ACTIVE'
AND a.type      = 'USER'
ORDER BY sql_exec_start ASC;
```

However, I can see that it is returning some queries that have already finished. Why would that happen?

Oracle Version 12.1.0 Enterprise
SQL Developer Version 19.1

Answer (score 2):

V$SQLAREA has all the parsed cursors in SQL area or in  memory for execution. It can be both current and past SQL statements.
Those SQL statements will remain in V$SQLAREA until they automatically age out or until you cleared the shared pool.

You might want to use a query like this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM GV$SQL WHERE USERS_EXECUTING > 0;
```